# How does one overcome an error loading a sqlite file into colab?

Tags: python, sqlite, google-colaboratory, traceback

When I try to load `my_data.sqlite` I get an error that the sqlite is not defined.

```
import os, os.chdir('/content/'), !ls: 
drive, sample_data, my_data.sqlite

con = sqlite3.connect('content/my_data.sqlite')
```

The traceback is

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-81-565fe12c437c> in <module>()
----> 1 con = sqlite.connect('/content/my_data.sqlite')
NameError: name 'sqlite' is not defined
```

I have tried `con = sqlite3.connect('content/my_data.sqlite')` and `%sql con = sqlite3.connect('content/my_data.sqlite')` plus many other combinations.

```
con = sqlite3.connect('content/my_data.sqlite')
%sql con = sqlite3.connect('content/my_data.sqlite')
```

Comment: Are you importing the sqlite3 module?

Comment: Thank you @Shawn for your insight. 'import sqlite3' performed the magic trick.   Yee P I O I A !